# Show post/page into div using function

Tags: php, functions, html

i'm new in php and want to show page content into a div. The call of the content is using function, here is my code but it doesnt works, how can I fix it?

```
function fields_after_order_details(){
  echo '<div class="tandc">'.
      $my_id = 2731;
      $post_id_2731 = get_post($my_id, ARRAY_A);
      $title = $post_id_2731['post_content'];
    .'</div>';
}
```

Comment: What is `ARRAY_A`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what ARRAY_A is supposed to be, seems unnecessary unless there's more info we're missing.  Also, `get_post` returns an object, not an array.  Try this:

```
function fields_after_order_details(){
  $my_id = 2731;
  $post_id_2731 = get_post($my_id);
  $title = $post_id_2731->post_content;
  echo '<div class="tandc">' . $title . '</div>';
```

}